# Adding thousand separator while printing a number

Tags: python, optimization, numbers, decimal

I don't really know the "name" for this problem, so it might be a incorrect title, but the problem is simple, if I have a number

for example:

```
number = 23543
second = 68471243
```

I want to it make `print()` like this.

> 23,543
>   68,471,243

I hope this explains enough or else add comments.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You mean thousand separators?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only need to add comma as thousand separator and are using Python version 3.6 or greater:

```
print(f"{number:,g}")
```

This uses the formatted string literals style. The item in braces `{0}` is the object to be formatted as a string. The colon `:` states that output should be modified. The comma `,` states that a comma should be used as thousands separator and `g` is for general number. [[1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)]

With older Python 3 versions, without the f-strings:

```
print("{0:,g}".format(number))
```

This uses the format-method of the str-objects [[2](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)]. The item in braces `{0}` is a place holder in string, the colon `:` says that stuff should be modified. The comma `,` states that a comma should be used as thousands separator and `g` is for general number [[3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)]. The `format`-method of the string object is then called and the variable `number` is passed as an argument.

The 68,471,24,3 seems a bit odd to me. Is it just a typo?

[Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

[Python 3 str.format()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

[Python 3 Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: I updated the answer to contain the new formatted string literal -version.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is setting the locale to en_US.

Example:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
number = 23543
second = 68471243
print locale.format("%d", number, grouping=True)
print locale.format("%d", second, grouping=True)
```

prints:

```
23,543
68,471,243
```

Comment: Error: unsupported locale setting
`return _setlocale(category, locale)`

Comment: Which operative system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 but this will work on Linux?

Comment: On linux you can install new locales easily. I don't know how to do it in Windows 7 :(